# Update Spring 3.2.4 a 5.3.19 Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping'

Tags: spring, jboss-eap

Estoy actualizando un proyecto realizado con spring-3.2.4.RELEASE a versión 5.3.19, en código no me marca errores pero al momento de desplegar el war no compila, el proyecto está Java 8, corre en jboss EAP 7.3, no es proyecto Maven.

Da el siguiente exception donde se puede apreciar que está agarrando las dos versiones en vez de sólo la 5.3.19:

Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.obtainApplicationContext()Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) [**spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE**]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:289) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:915) [**spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19**]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.obtainApplicationContext()Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.detectMappedInterceptors(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:407) [**spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19**]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:380) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119) [**spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE**]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]

Este es mi archivo de configuración: ws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<import resource="aop.xml" />
<import resource="transactions.xml" />
<import resource="rmi.xml" />
<import resource="jms.xml" />
<import resource="rdm.xml"/>
<import resource="cache.xml"/>

<bean id="airTime" class="AirTimeImpl" parent="airTimeAbstract" />

<bean id="airTimeAbstract" class="AirTimeImplAbstract">
    <property name="airTime" ref="airTime" />
</bean>

<bean id="t360AirTime" parent="serviceProxy" scope="prototype">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="AirTimeImpl">
            <property name="transactionsServiceImpl" ref="transactionsServiceImpl" />
            <property name="crmFactory" ref="crmRemotingFactory" />
            <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
            <property name="queuePackage" ref="queuePackage" />
            <property name="ewalletFactory" ref="ewalletRemotingFactory" />
            <property name="mvoInterfaceFactory" ref="mvoInterfaceRemotingFactory" />
            <property name="service" ref="service" />
            <property name="secureRandom" ref="secureRandom" />
            <property name="jmsProducer" ref="jmsProducer" />   
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="offerFactory" class="OfferFactoryImpl" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="offerServiceClient" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="targetEprOffer" />
</bean>

<bean id="offerServiceClient" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.client.RPCServiceClient" />

<bean id="targetEprOffer" class="org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{systemProperties['OFFER_ENDPOINT']}" />
</bean></beans>
```

cabe señalar que todos los archivos que se importan tienen:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

Las librerías del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo intento levantar en el servidor de desarrollo, me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El proyecto depende de otros dos proyectos que seguían en la versión 3.2.4 de Spring, al actualizar estos proyectos se resolvió el problema de la incompatibilidad.